# Python: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I am attempting to use the following function to simulate loads on a beam:

```
def simulateBeamRun(personList, beam, times):
```

I have come up with the following code so far:

```
def createPersonList(fileName):
    """Function will go through each line of file and
    create a person object using the data provided in
    the line and add it to a list
    """
    theFile = open(fileName)
    next(theFile)
    #array = []
    for line in theFile:
        aList = line.split(',')
        bList = map(lambda s: s.strip('\n'), aList)
        cList = [float(i) for i in bList]
        print cList

def simulateBeamRun(personList, beam, times):
    """Takes a list of times covering the duration of
    the simulation (0-35 s), the list of person
    objects and a beam object to simulate a beam run
    """
    dList = []
    for time in times:
        eList = []
        for person in personList:
            loadTuples = personModel.person.loadDisplacement(time)
            if beamModel.beam.L > loadTuples[1] > 0:
                 eList.append(loadTuples)
            else:
                return None
        beamModel.beam.setLoads(eList)
        dList.append(beamModel.beam.getMaxDeflection())
```

However, I am getting the following error when trying to run the function (before I give it any inputs:

```
for person in personList:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `personList` is `None`. Relevant parts of your code are missing.

Comment: You need to make sure that personList is not None

Comment: Added relevant code. How would I make personList not None.

Comment: You should be returning `cList` not printing it

Comment: That was just for when I was checking my code

Comment: I think, in createPersonList(), it should return [] instead of None sometimes

Comment: @Student1001 [float(i) for i in []] return []. [] is iterable. in this case, the error will not happen. when theFile is nothing, the program will not go to the loop (for line in theFile), it will return None

Comment: @BAE would it be ok if I pm'ed you for help. I still haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: @Student1001 OK. I did not received your pm yet...

Comment: Sorry I don't think I have enough rep to start one. Could you send me one please?

Answer (score 5):

In order to be iterated, `personList` needs to have some values in it.

If you're creating `personList` with the function `createPersonList`, then you need to [return a value](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm). Otherwise, that list doesn't exist outside of `createPersonList`.

```
def createPersonList(fileName):
    # do stuff to create cList
    return cList

personList = createPersonList(myFile)
```

Then, `personList` will have values and you can use it in subsequent functions.

```
simulateBeamRun(personList, beam, times)
```

If you want to avoid running that loop at all in cases where `personList` doesn't have values, include a conditional.

```
if personList is None:
    print "No values in personList"
else:
    for person in personList:
        # do stuff with person
```

Answer (score 2):

May the following code help

```
def createPersonList(fileName):
    """Function will go through each line of file and
    create a person object using the data provided in
    the line and add it to a list"""
    cList=[]#see my comments. if the following loop not happen, still return []

    theFile = open(fileName)
    next(theFile)
    #array = []
    for line in theFile:
        aList = line.split(',')
        bList = map(lambda s: s.strip('\n'), aList)
        cList += [float(i) for i in bList]# if bList is iterable, [float(i) for i in bList] should be a list (including [])
    return cList#according to your comments, should return here.
```

float(i) may throw errors, so use try-except.
I think checking related to personList should be done in this function, error info should be logged.