# Error with pygame object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
#campaign module for blunt wars
import pygame
import time
import sys

pygame.init()

size = [400, 400]
width = size[0]
height = size[1]

#colors
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)
#end colors

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption('Blunt Wars - Campaign')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#updates screen res
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type ==pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)

text = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 30)

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+y > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic,(x,y,w,h))
        smallText = pygame.font.Sysfont('Arial',20)
        textSurf, TextRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
        screen.blit(textSurf, TextRect)

def intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                #import Blunt_Wars

        screen.fill(blue)
        header = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial',115)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Blunt Wars - Campaign", header)
        textRect.center = ((width/2),(height/2))
        screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)

        button("Start New",400,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def game_loop():
    print("game loop ran")
    pygame.quit()
    quit()


intro()
```

So this is my whole program and im trying to make a main menu but when i run this code i get this error:

```
textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Blunt Wars - Campaign", header)
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not iterable.
```

I don't get why is is doing this but if someone can help me that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616870/python-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable)

Comment: type(pygame.Surface) = ?

Comment: `text_objects` returns a Surface, so why are you trying to unpack it into a Surface and a Rect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text_objects` function returns a `pygame.Surface` but you're trying to unpack this surface into the variables `textSurf, TextRect` in the `button` function and since `pygame.Surface`s are not iterable, the `TypeError` gets raised:

```
textSurf, TextRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
```

To fix the error, you can create the `textRect` with the [`pygame.Surface.get_rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) method in the `text_objects` function and return the surface and the rect as a tuple. Then you can unpack this tuple in the `button` function:

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    # Create the text rect.
    textRect = textSurface.get_rect()
    # Return a tuple consisting of the surface and the rect.
    return textSurface, textRect

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+y > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic,(x,y,w,h))
        smallText = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial',20)  # Typo: Sysfont -> SysFont
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)  # Typo: TextRect -> textRect
        textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
        screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)  # Typo: TextRect -> textRect
```

I've also corrected some typos.

By the way, I recommend creating the font objects once in the global scope and then reuse them in the rest of the program for reasons of efficiency (this `smallText = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial',20)` should be in the global scope).

Answer (score 1):

Look into that:

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface

textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Blunt Wars - Campaign", header)
```

`text_objects()` returns the result of `font.render()` which is a `pygame.Surface` instance.

It is not iterable and that's why your unpacking is not working...